# Angular - bind public/private properties

Tags: angular, binding

I'm doing angular tutorial at [angular.io](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), where I read:

> ```
> constructor(**public** messageService: MessageService) {}
> ```
>
> The `messageService` property must be **`public`** because you're about to bind to it in the template.
>
> Angular only binds to **`public`** component properties.

I emphasize **`public`** there.

However, if I change **`public`** to **`private`** there, everything works as before...

So please guide me to place where I can dispel my doubts.

My Angular version: 5.0.0,

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, AOT compilation will complaint about `private` property, AOT bundles are also preferred for prod build..

Answer (score 2):

This is just a recommendation so that your project is compatible with AOT (Ahead Of Time) type build process. You can see its impact by creating  an AOT build with this command:

```
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used Angular CLI to build your application, at some version CLI would swallow the errors that Angular would throw when building an app. With the CLI update they started showing the errors to the user eventually and stopping the application from building successfully.

Check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5623#issuecomment-289075279) issue on GitHub for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're right, but in production mode you can't change public to private.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB3yH.png) show the error in production mode